Call Custom Function when user clicks on a FormIO Text Field in react
I have a form implemented in formio which has couple of fields (FirstName, LastName). I am trying to do a simple POC to alert the firstName, LastName when user clicks on text field.
I have tried it with the code available on internet and via chatGPT but not able to get the success.
I need help how can I implement this functionality in react project.

provide some of your already existing code ( which is not working ). If you've tried any other variations, provide them as well.
